# Do any of the live-action DC Comics based shows share a continuity?

Tags: tv, dc

I understand that the live-action TV shows are separate from the comics, and that the recent/upcoming DC movies are separate from the TV shows, **but do any of the shows share a continuity universe?**

Before I stopped watching, the Green Arrow appeared in *Smallville*, and I remember hearing that the show *Arrow* was pitched as a spin-off, but I believe it uses a different actor.

I know there was also the short lived *Birds of Prey* series, and apparently *Human Target* is based off of a DC property as well.

Comment: I thought the new Arrow was a spinoff too, but when I watched it they've clearly made it its own continuity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOT YET:**

All of the aired [television series based on any DC property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_series_based_on_DC_Comics) do not share the same continuity.  Smallville did feature it's own version of Oliver Queen, however he is not the same Oliver Queen who appears in [Arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28TV_series%29).  However, the character of Barry Allen who appeared on an episode of Arrow will be staring in his own [Flash series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flash_%282014_TV_series%29), produced by the same company and taking place in the same universe as Arrow, with the possibility of a crossover (probably during sweeps week).  With the upcoming series [Gotham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotham_%28TV_series%29) being owned and produced by Warner Brothers, and airing on Fox, and the [John Constantine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellblazer#Adaptations) series being under development for NBC the chances of any of them sharing continuity with Arrow and the Flash (who are owned and produced by the CW) is highly unlikely.