# Are all the Dc live action heroes from movies and TV universes exist in the same universe but as different earths in the multitverse

Tags: dc

There have been hundreds of live action dc heroes and villans played by mutiple  actors in tv and movies like some old serials, The 1950s  George Reeves "Adventures of Superman,"1966"s Batman 1970"s Wonder Woman Superman '78 (including Supergirl '84) two "Swamp Things," a "Superboy" TV series, and Batman '89-'97 (Burton and Schumacher) The 1990"s Flash  "Lois & Clark." Smallville" 2001-11, The Dark knight Trilogy The Arrowverse Arrow, Flash, Legends, Constantine, Supergirl and Earth 2(Jay Garrick et al.) The Gotham series on Fox Man of Steel/DC Cinematic U , Green Lantern 2011  so Are all the Dc live action heroes from movies and TV universes exist in the same universe but as different earths in the multitverse

Comment: Are you asking if there are multiple earths in the same universe?

Comment: sort of im asking Are all the Dc live action heroes from movies and TV universes exist in the same universe but as different earths in the multitverse

Comment: There are multiple universes. Each one has one earth. They’re all in the same multiverse... pretty sure.

Comment: If someone's asking for clarification and all you do is paste the content that already exists... that's not really going to clarify anything.

Comment: so i wont get any anwsers

Comment: im not pasteing the content that already exists

Comment: I get the feeling that you don’t understand what we’re saying. Anyway, would you please state your question in different words?

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: Ask your question in your own words. Words in an order that you haven’t already used. Or did my comment above answer your question?

Comment: so i wont get any anwsers

Comment: Not if you don’t ask your question, no.

Comment: but i did ask my question im asking if   all the Dc live action heroes from movies and TV universes exist in the same universe but as different earths in the multitverse

Comment: -1 for lack of punctuation making your question a pain to read.

Comment: how do i fix it

Comment: Not all of the shows you list are in the same universe. For example, the Arrowverse contains only [these TV shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowverse#Television_series). Does that help at all?

Comment: sort of im asking if all the Dc live action heroes from movies and TV universes exist in the same universe but ! as different earths in the multitverse

Comment: remember but as different earths in the multitverse

Comment: @AndrewCasali I don't think you understand what the multiverse is. There are a bunch of football fields, each with their own ball. The DC heros (for the most part) each live on their football field, not on another ball on the same field. Does this analogy make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, a couple definitions...**

In a standard *universe*, there is only 1 ("uni-") of each individual thing. One Earth, one Milky Way, one Superman, one Flash, etc. Even when someone gets cloned, there's still the original and clone A, clone B, clone C...

A *multiverse* ("multi-" = many) is the collection of all the connected universes. The multiverse contains universes--not the other way around. So there's an Earth-1 in Universe-1, an Earth-2 in Universe-2, an Earth-3 in Universe-3, and so on. Think of a bag of inflated balloons. Each balloon is a universe, and the bag holding the ballons is the multiverse.

Earth-1 is sometimes referred to as "Earth-Prime" with its universe being the "main" universe. In our human-centric stories, Earth/Earth-Prime is often considered the dramatic focal point of the universe and often the multiverse as well.

Sometimes the differences are minor (the sky is pink instead of blue), and sometimes the differences are major (the Nazis win WW2). There is both a [Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_(Marvel_Comics)) and a [DC multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_(DC_Comics)), as well as other multiverses not belonging to either (citation needed).

**Now to your answer...**

In the movies and TV, pretty much each time a DC character is portrayed by a different actor, you're seeing a different universe--but they're all part of the same DC multiverse. In other words, there's the George Reeves universe, the Christopher Reeve universe, the Tom Welling universe, the Dean Cain universe... But each of those universes is part of the DC Multiverse.

Occasionally an actor in a series is simply replaced with another actor ([Rachel Dawes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/why-didnt-katie-holmes-play-rachel-dawes-in-the-dark-knight) in the Nolan Batman movies, [Rhodey in Iron Man](http://screenrant.com/why-terrence-howard-didnt-return-for-iron-man-2-salary/)), but the rest of the cast remains the same and the story stays in the same universe.

And here's [another person asking basically the same thing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51309/do-any-of-the-live-action-dc-comics-based-shows-share-a-continuity?rq=1).

Comment: this whole anwser In the movies and TV, pretty much each time a DC character is portrayed by a different actor, you're seeing a different universe--but they're all part of the same DC multiverse. In other words, there's the George Reeves universe, the Christopher Reeve universe, the Tom Welling universe, the Dean Cain universe... But each of those universes is part of the DC Multiverse. means  they do exist in the same universe but as different earths in the multiverse

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO NO

Comment: universe means the galaxy and our earth and many planets  and multiverse means different earths a mirror-world.  a parallel universe that's very, very similar to ours  and with many different earths are nearly identical to ours. And they all exist at the same time, giving us endless alternatives to what we have here.

Comment: @AndrewCasali OK, but weren’t you asking whether all of the shows were in the same universe? Your definition of “universe” looks good, and you know that a multiverse is bigger than a universe. No, the shows do not share a universe. They share a multiverse.

Comment: @AndrewCasali Wait, I am not quite sure what you meant. Lots of universes fit in a multiverse. A multiverse isn’t just an alternate universe: it’s the thing that holds _every_ alternate universe. Is that what you were saying?

Comment: i know they share a multiverse but im asking  Do all the DC live action heroes from movies and TV universes exist in the same universe but as different earths in the multiverse?

Comment: @AndrewCasali No. The answer to your question is, no. They do not share a universe.

Comment: @AndrewCasali I'm going to try this one more time. Think of a bag of peaches. The bag is the multiverse. Each peach is a universe. Each peach has a single pit/stone--that's the Earth. There is only one stone/Earth per peach/universe. The bag/multiverse has many peaches/universes, and therefore has many stones/Earths. But the stones/Earths aren't lose in the bag/multiverse. Each one is contained in its own peach/universe.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40579/discussion-on-answer-by-miltonaut-do-all-the-dc-live-action-heroes-from-movies-a).